# How to store an array as single row for each value in my database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel

the whole idea is that when a user click on checkbox and save, the form should be submitted with an array containing the checked values, and save them in the database as single row for each value. i don't know if this is possible but i'm sure you guys have a solution or can help me?

and here's my form:

```
<div class="">

        <form style="width: 70%" method="POST" action="{{ URL('/admin/projects/services/save') }}"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">

            @csrf

            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{ @$id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="projectid" id="projectid" value="{{ @$projectid }}">
            
            


            <div class="row topSpacer">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <p class="bold">Selected Services: <span class="red">*</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">

                    <input type="text" id="selectedServices" name="selectedServices" value="" readonly>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row topSpacer">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <p class="bold">Select a service: <span class="red">*</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    
                    @foreach ($services as $service)
                        <input type="checkbox" name="service" value="<?php echo stripslashes($service->id); ?>">
                        <label for="service"><?php echo stripslashes($service->name); ?></label>
                        <br>
                        <hr>
                    @endforeach

                    @error('service')
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row topSpacerHuge">
                <div class="col-12 textRight">
                    <button type="button"
                        onclick="window.location='{{ url('admin/projects/services/index/'.$projectid) }}'"
                        class="goBackBtn">Cancel</button>
                    <input class="saveBtn" id="saveBtn" type="submit" value="Save">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and my script to get checkboxes value:

```
<script>
        $(function() {

            $("input:checkbox[name='service']").click(function() {
                $value = [];
                
                $.each($("input:checkbox[name='service']:checked"), function() {
                    $value.push($(this).val());
                    $array = $value.join();
                    
                });
                // console.log(value.join(", "));
                $("#selectedServices").val($array);
            })
            
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the problem? Store it as you want.

Comment: how to do that in the controller? how can i get each array value and store it as single value?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem, a jQuery problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide your database storage code.

Comment: you just need to iterate through your array in order to store those values in your database. In java you can use "preparedStatement" for a better/safer performance, there must be something similar in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

for implementing  checked values I  recommend to use the select tag
and you can give A name attribute with [] and it will collect all of your data
for example , look at my project's file which I'm trying to collect name of some users :

```
         <select name="users[]" id="example-with-maxHeight" class="multiselect-group" multiple >
                   @foreach($users as $user)
            <option  @if($user->average < $averageParticipate )class="alert-danger" @endif value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}} - {{$user->average}}</option>
                   @endforeach
        </select>
```

have attention to users[] in name attribute
now in your request you can access all of your checked items .

if we look at your code ,can be some thing like this :

```
<label for="service"><?php echo stripslashes($service->name); ?></label>
       <select name="services[]" id="" class="multiselect-group" multiple >
        @foreach($users as $user)
              <option value = "{{$sevice->id}}"> <?php echo stripslashes($service->name); ?></option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
```

now in your controllers you can access them :

```
request->get('services');
```

it will give you back an array of selected items .

Notice that id attribute helps me to interact with my java script code
you can rename it to yourselves .